# Yii2 DbSession exception

Tags: php, session, yii2

I'm using DbSession to store session in the database.
From time to time I can face this exception when I try to login.

Maybe somebody handle this issue somehow or I'm doing something wrong?

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `session` SET `id`=0 WHERE `id`='3u5r7gq6pqh8s0gjrusfqpmni7'
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1062
    [2] => Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

in /var/www/develop/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 844
```

Comment: This indicates that `session_id()` is not properly returned. Have you got any custom session configuration or implementation?

Comment: No, there is no custom configurations or implementations. By the way, I'm using `php7`. Also, I though maybe this issue is linked with https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/1812, but I'm not sure(it seems I should receive another error message).

Comment: This may be the case of race condition but `DbSession` should check if `session_id()` has been returned properly. I think this qualifies for an issue at [Yii 2 Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/new).

Comment: I've created [new issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/13212) on GitHub. Thanks.